# How is a SortedList with SortedLists as keys ordered? (C#)

Tags: c#, sorting, generics, key, sortedlist

I'm trying to create a SortedList that contains SortedLists as keys and I want them to be ordered by the first element on the key.

However, I do not know how to find information about how different sorted lists compare to each other (do they use the pointer/address value? Do they use the first element of the list? Etc.)

I thought about creating a class that inherits SortedList (so the keys of the outer SortedList would be of this new personalized class type) but I'm struggling because I can not find what characteristics the Key and Value must have (to define the generic constraints).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want a dictionary like : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,List<string>>>?

Comment: Using a `SortedList` as a key will not be useful as it's going to use reference values for comparing.  Why not just get that first value out and make it the key?  Maybe if you explain exactly how you want to use this data structure we can recommend one for you.

Comment: I'm trying to make a multiplayer game that has traps in it. I need to have a sorted list that contains all the traps sorted by the nearest character but having access to all the characters in the range of the trap. In other words: I need a List of Traps that contains a list of the characters in each trap (both lists sorted). @juharr

Comment: Right now I have this code: https://i.imgur.com/CF7Wzsx.png Not as clean as I would like but it does the trick. It would be nice if sorted list were compared by the elements in it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As juharr said, using a SortedList as a key in a SortedList will sort it using the reference values for comparing.

I did not manage it to sort it the way I wanted but I got an answer.